# Buttons on bottom of a page when clicked, entire page is scrolling to top and then moving to next page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following scenario for mobile development using HTML5 (using HTML5 and jquerymobile)

How to restrict a page scrolling to the top before it navigates to the next screen?

I have **page1**, where there is a button on the bottom of the page (it needs to be scrolled-down to the bottom to find the button). This button, when clicked should navigate to an another page- say **page2**.

Being on bottom of the page, when I click on the button - the **page1** is first going to the top and then navigating to **page2**. Is there a way to restrict this process? - the navigation should happen from **page1** to **page2** directly from bottom of **page1**

Here's some code to follow --

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="shopsMenuPage">     
  <div data-role="content" >
    <h3>Shops &amp; Hangouts</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" >
      <li id="restaurantsList" data-icon="info"><a href="#foodNBeverages" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/foodNBeverages.png" />
        <h3> Food &amp; Beverages</h3>
        </a></li>
      <li id="dutyFreeList" data-icon="info"><a id="dutyFree" href="#foodNBeverages" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/dutyFree.png"/>
        <h3> Duty Free Shops</h3>
        </a></li>
      <li id="florists" data-icon="info"><a href="#foodNBeverages" id="flowers" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/flowers.png" />
        <h3> Flower Shops</h3>
        </a></li>
      <li id="bookShopList" data-icon="info"><a href="#foodNBeverages" id="books" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/bookShop.png" />
        <h3> Book Shops</h3>
        </a></li>
      <li id="musicStores" data-icon="info"><a href="#foodNBeverages" id="music" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/music.png" />
        <h3> Music Store </h3>
        </a></li>
      <li id="garAndAcc" data-icon="info"><a href="#foodNBeverages" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/garments.png" />
        <h3> Garments &amp; Accessories </h3>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

This is actually a listview (jquerymobile), with multiple `<li>`s - each `href`-ed to a new page.

Now, when I scroll down to the last `<li>` and click on it to navigate to next screen, the screen is first moving to the first `<li>` and then navigating to the next screen.
As mentioned earlier, this is not for a website, it is for a mobile app being developed with html5 and jquerymobile

Comment: There's no way we can help without you showing us some code.

Comment: you should include relevant markup/code in your question

Comment: So you're saying that the mobile browser is unexpectedly scrolling back to the top before loading your new page? What browser is this? Could it be a side-effect from a piece of Javascript that gets executed on form submission? Is it specific to this mobile browser or is it repeatable on a regular desktop browser?

Comment: @VladislavQulin - I posted some code here.. please check

Comment: @koala_dev I posted some code here.. please check

Comment: @MiklosAubert -- no it's not on a browser.. it's on a mobile app being developed with html5 and jquerymobile using phonegap (for android)

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem : you're using `data-transition=slide`, so when jQuery Mobile does the animation, it needs to scroll back up so that the original viewport and the new viewport are lined up. Otherwise, if your second page wasn't as long, it would slide to an empty zone. Your question actually looks like a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802134/jquery-mobile-go-back-button-scrolls-to-top). Read [Gajotres' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15805031/2067786) for more details. I suggest you simply use a different animation style.

Comment: ah! sorry @MiklosAubert - i somehow missed the existing question on SO... thank you for directing me there...
I will try using a different animation style...